# Stop detach pipelines from getting created

Tags: gitlab

I had a gitlab job defined as follows.

```
test-1:
  stage: test
  only:
    variables:
    - $RUN_TEST
  except:
  - tags
```

and then I changed that job to run based on gitlab rules.

```
test-1:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "schedule" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null'
    - if: '$RUN_TESTS == "true" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null'
```

After this change, Whenever I commit some change to my branch, I am getting two pipeline runs in my gitlab project. One is for the latest commit I have made and second as detached.

How can I get rid of detached pipeline run?

Another interesting thing is, when I cancel the latest pipeline the detach pipeline also got cancelled.

For latest pipeline, value of CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE = push and for detach pipeline, value of CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE = merge_request_event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The detached pipelines you are seeing are merge request pipelines. You can use `workflow:rules` to control when a pipeline is created. To prevent merge request pipelines:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - when: always
```